# Chart js how to toggle line without click

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

I am knee-deep in a chart.js project and for the sake of simplicity, let's assume I have lines A, B, and C in a plain line chart. Is there any way to create a chart containing all 3 lines that only shows A & B, and has C crossed out in the legend and not displayed on the graph itself? (toggled like it was clicked.)

The exact functionality i'm trying to have is
 
1. generate lines A, B, and C
 
2. simulate onClick() onto line C

I think I'm overlooking something really simple and want to be sure before I go rewriting chart.js source code. I have searched the docs with no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle.

Comment: @SagarR got it https://jsfiddle.net/bg65oLje/6/

Answer (score 0):

ok, so it was really simple.

data for a line that isn't hidden. (same as clicked)

```
  {
        label: Object.keys(data)[i],
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: color,
        borderColor: color,
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        pointBorderColor: color,
        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: color,
        pointHoverBorderColor: color,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        data: data[Object.keys(data)[i]]
      }
```

and data for a line that is hidden (clicked)

```
  {
        hidden: true,
        label: Object.keys(data)[i],
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: color,
        borderColor: color,
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        pointBorderColor: color,
        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: color,
        pointHoverBorderColor: color,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHitRadius: 10,
        data: data[Object.keys(data)[i]]
      }
```

only difference is

```
hidden: true
```

simple fix.